# Pytanie Threads, communication beetwen one and the other processes

Tags: python, multithreading

its my code with socket client-server:

```
def receive_remote(device, queue):
    while True:
        try:
            xbee_message=device.read_data()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error in read data on receive_remote: %s" %e)

        if xbee_message is not None:
             print("Data received")
             print(xbee_message.data.decode())

        time.sleep(100 / 1000)

class SocketClientObject(object):

    def __init__(self, socket, address ):
        self.socket = socket
        self.address = address

class ClientThread(threading.Thread):

   def __init__(self, client_object, device, remote_device):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.client_object = client_object

    def run(self):

        data = 1
        while data:
            try:
                data = self.client_object.socket.recv(1024)
            except:
                print("error in receive data from socket")


device = XBeeDevice(PORT_D, BAUD_RATE)
device.open()

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

sock.bind(SOCK_ADDR)
sock.listen(0)
print("Start listening on [ %s:%s ]" % (HOST, str(PORT)))

ct = ClientThread( SocketClientObject( clientsocket, address ))
ct.daemon = True
ct.start()

td_receive_remote = threaded = threading.Thread(target=receive_remote, args=(device,))
td_receive_remote.daemon = True
td_receive_remote.start()
```

And now how to send data to client socket from the "receive_remote" thread? How to exchange data between threads. Maybe queue but I don't want another loop in the client. Thank you for all the suggestions.

Thanks for help.

Comment: ``queue.Queue`` allows to safely exchange data, but you can also just share mutable objects directly. Where to and from do you want to exchange data? What makes you think you'd need another loop for that? What's the point of ``ClientThread``? It doesn't actually do anything with its messages. Do you want to communicate between processes or threads? Your title says both.

Comment: I want from def in thread "receive_remote (from the device)" send data to client socket. PS. I've completed the code

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use sockets for in-process communication? Sockets, especially AF_INET, are only needed for communication between processes.

Comment: I do not understand. data received from other devices and I want to send to the socket that sent the request.

Comment: so the question is how to send a thread to a sock that is in a different thread ....